Mapping Discriminated Union to function returning its values gives strange function union types
I'm trying to implement a generic component for my project that is able to use any object type and produce value parsing functions returning correct values. All seemed to work fine untill i tested it with a Discriminated Union type.
type ExpectedTypeValues =  "foo" | "bar"
type DummyType = {
    type: "foo"
} | {
    type: "bar"
}
type MappingUtility<ObjType extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
    [key in keyof ObjType]: () => ObjType[key]
};
let type: ExpectedTypeValues

const obj1: MappingUtility<DummyType> = {
    type: () => type
}

const obj2: {
    [key in keyof DummyType]: () => DummyType[key]
} = {
    type: () => type
}

type test1 = (typeof obj1)["type"]
type test2 = (typeof obj2)["type"]

Playground example
I would expect both obj1 and obj2 to be valid, but the typing engine acts differently in these two cased. And the differences are clear, test1 expects a union of functions returning exact strings
type test1 = (() => "foo") | (() => "bar")

while test2 properly makes it
type test2 = () => "foo" | "bar"

Am i missing something, some behaviour of generics that i don't realize?

Homomorphic mapped types over generic type parameters are distributive over unions, whereas such mapped types over specific types do not distribute over unions. See the answer to the linked question above, and ms/TS#12447 which implemented this behavior.

Yeah, that seems to be it, thank you.
